# Referring to a fragment after adding it multiple times

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, fragment

I am creating an alarm application, the alarm options are a fragment activity. A new instance of the activity should be added for every new alarm, I got to that point and I am able to do it correctly, even to modify parameters in each one of the fragments by defining onClickListeners inside of them. But now I want to refer to the variables that I created in the fragment's java class, and I have no idea how because I just added them and I don't know their names or anything.

Activity in which i create new instances of the fragments:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_alarms);

    final android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

    Button button_newAlarm = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_new_alarm);
    button_newAlarm.setOnClickListener(
            new Button.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {   //CREATES A NEW ALARM
                    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                    alarm_fragment alarmFragment = new alarm_fragment();
                    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.alarmListContainer,alarmFragment);
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
                }

                ;
            }
    );

}
```

One of the variables I am modifying in the fragment's class

```
public class alarm_fragment extends Fragment {
    public boolean check_sunday = true;    

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_alarm_fragment, container, false);

        final TextView button_check_sunday = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.check_sunday);
        button_check_sunday.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        if (check_sunday) {
                            button_check_sunday.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                            check_sunday = false;
                        } else {
                            button_check_sunday.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                            check_sunday = true;
                        }
                    };
                }
        );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that instead of adding the same fragment over and over i actually had to create a new one and add it every time, to make it easy to name i created:

```
    final AlarmFragment[] alarmFragment = new AlarmFragment[7];
```

and then inside the `OnClickListener(`

```
 if (alarmsAmount < 7) { // SETS THE MAX AMMOUNT OF ALARMS
                        alarmFragment[alarmsAmount] = new AlarmFragment();
                        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.alarmListContainer, alarmFragment[alarmsAmount]); 
                        fragmentTransaction.commit();
                        alarmsAmount++;
```

By using that and then for example `alarmFragment[x].isCheckSunday()` you can read the elemnt's variables and modify them

I hope this can help anyone facing the same problem i did.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're referring to the member variable *check_sunday*. Make it static.

```
public static boolean check_sunday = true;
```

By the way, use proper Java naming convention. It's easier to understand.
Change *alarm_fragment* to *AlarmFragment*, *check_sunday* to *sCheckSunday* (because it is static now), and so on.
You can refer [Google's Java style guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html#s5-naming) for that.

Comment: I believe the intention is to set up one alarm each for each fragment rather than accessing the same static alarm. setting in every fragment?

Comment: I found out that by using an integer to set the alarm "number" i am able to identify fragments via the TAG ( `fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.alarmListContainer, alarmFragment, String.valueOf(alarmsAmount)); `) 
Now i still dont know how to refer to these variables.